# Getting undefined index while trying to submit a form with JQuery Ajax to communicate with the Mailchimp API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mailchimp

I am trying to save emails to a list using the mailchimp API and unable to move forward due to the following error:

```
Undefined index: email in /var/www/html/subscribe.php on line 9
```

the code on line 9 is: `'email_address'     => $_POST['email'],`

html:

```
<form name="SubsribeForm1" id="SubsribeForm1">
  <input name="email" id="emailAdd" type="text" />
  <p class="err"><span id="msg"></span></p>
  <button id="SubscribeEmail">Submit</button>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$('#reset-modal').click(function() {
  $('#msg').html("");
});

$(document).on("click", "#SubscribeEmail", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var emailAdd = $('input[name="email"]').val();
  console.log(emailAdd);

  var data = {
    email: $("#emailAdd").val()
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: "subscribe.php",
    data: data,
    method: "POST",
    timeout: 15000,
  }).done(function( msg ) {
    $( "#msg" ).html( msg );
  }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
  });
});
```

subscribe.php:

```
require("_mc.php");

use \DrewM\Mail

Chimp\MailChimp;

$MailChimp = new MailChimp('7d446f0db3c6f9e4b5f9b6f35a587fad-us10');
$result = $MailChimp->post('lists/02801ed82a/members', array(
  'email_address'     => $_POST['email'],
  'status'            => 'subscribed'
));

if($result){
    $status = $result["status"];

if($status == "subscribed"){
    echo "Great! We will keep you updated on our progress.";
}
else{
    echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again.";
}
```

}

I have made sure the form input had the name that matches the POST variable. I followed the following example: https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/blob/master/README.md

Not sure if this is a problem with the JS or PHP code.

Comment: You try to POST a JSON array the data : var data = {
    email: $("#emailAdd").val()
  }; try data = "email=" + $("#emailAdd").val();

Comment: Add `dataType: "json"` to your ajax request. Also, change `method: "POST"` to `type: "post"`.